# Concise way of composing Java method references?

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8, method-reference

Given some Java 8 method functions:

```
class Foo { Bar getBar() {} }
class Bar { Baz getBaz() {} }
```

A composition of the two accessors looks like:

```
Function<Foo, Bar> getBarFromFoo = Foo::getBar;
Function<Bar, Baz> getBazFromBar = Bar::getBaz;
Function<Foo, Baz> getBazFromFoo = getBarFromFoo.andThen(getBazFromBar);
```

Is there a more concise way? This seems to work

```
((Function<Foo, Bar>) Foo::getBar).andThen(Bar::getBaz)
```

But it's rather ugly. The outer parens make sense for precedence reasons, but why is the cast necessary?

(`Foo::getBar::getBaz` would be nice, but alas...)

Comment: Why not do `foo -> foo.getBar()::getBaz`? Seems like you're overcomplicating it. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @VinceEmigh, did you mean `foo -> foo.getBar().getBaz()`? otherwise, it makes no sense

Comment: @VinceEmigh, the way you suggested is not flexible enough. It is much better to prepare simple mappers (`a->b`, `b->c`) composing them with simple operations like `Function`'s `compose`, `andThen` at runtime rather than building up all possible cases at compile time.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko You could use currying if flexibility is a concern: `foo -> bar -> bar::getBaz`

Comment: @VinceEmigh, you can't use `foo -> bar -> bar::getBaz` to achieve a map series (here, to get a `Baz` as output). It could return sth like `Function<Foo, Function<Bar, Function<Bar, Baz>>>` which doesn't make sense

Answer (score 10):

Let's define a functional interface:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface MyFunctionalInterface {
    Bar getBar(Foo f);
}
```

We can simplify the method reference `Foo::getBar` a bit,

```
(Foo foo) -> foo.getBar();
```

which means *"take a `Foo` and return a `Bar`"*. For that description, a lot of methods are suitable (for instance, our interface with the `getBar` and a `Funtion<Foo, Bar>` with its `apply`):

```
MyFunctionalInterface f1 = (Foo foo) -> foo.getBar();
Function<Foo, Bar> f2 = (Foo foo) -> foo.getBar();
```

*That is the answer to the question why the cast is necessary.*

---

To answer the question whether there is a more concise way affirmatively, we have to set a context. The context unambiguously gives us a `Function` to continue working with:

```
class Functions {
    public static <I, O> Function<I, O> of(Function<I, O> function) {
        return function;
    }
}

Functions.of(Foo::getBar).andThen(Bar::getBaz);
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no dedicated way of composing functions in Java other than `andThen()`.

You need to perform the cast because `Foo::getBar` is ambiguous. **It could match every interface having similar method signature.

Unfortunately, `((Function<Foo, Bar>) Foo::getBar).andThen(Bar::getBaz)` is the best you can do.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just use a lambda expression?

```
x -> x.getBar().getBaz()
```

There is no other way to compose functions other than what you already suggested because of type ambiguity. This is not even much longer than `Foo::getBar::getBaz`

Answer (score 0):

That's the best you are going to get. If you think that this would work:

```
Foo::getBar::getBaz
```

it will not.  That's because `Foo::getBar` is a *poly expression* - it depends on the context used - it could be a `Function`, but could also be a `Predicate` for example; so it could potentially apply to many things, so the cast is just necessary there.

You could hide that behind a method that would do the chaining and `andThen`, but the problem is still there.

**EDIT**

See an example here:

```
public static void cool(Predicate<Integer> predicate) {

}

public static void cool(Function<Integer, String> function) {

}
```

and the expression `cool(i -> "Test");` will fail to compile

Comment: Thanks. I know it won't work. Just wishing... The type inferencer should know it's not a predicate because it doesn't return boolean.  I'm not a Java type inference wizard, but it seems logical that since  Foo::getBar satisfies any functional interface of the form Foo->Bar and getBaz satisfies Bar->Baz, then it seems reasonable that `Foo::getBar::getBaz` is a poly expression that satisfies any functional interface of the form Foo->Baz.

Comment: @Gene the `Predicate` and `Function` were just one example to prove that these are indeed poly expressions (see edit)... And `type inference` for lambdas and method references are not that obvious; that's the reason why probably this chaining was not implemented at all - it's *by far* not trivial

Comment: I've actually written a type inferencer. I know it's not trivial. That doesn't mean it's impossible.

Comment: @Gene I'm not saying it's impossible btw - it could be improved in some future idk version... just that at the moment, me personally, (and I am definitely not the right person for this), can't see a *real way* to do it safely.

Answer (score 0):

With [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava), you can use [Functions.compose](https://guava.dev/releases/28.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Functions.html#compose-com.google.common.base.Function-com.google.common.base.Function-):

```
import com.google.common.base.Functions;

...

Functions.compose(Bar::getBaz, Foo::getBar);
```